# Poisson Process (Expected Waiting Time) w Tree Diagram

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process, decision-trees

Hi everyone so I have a quick question.

Say for example we have a supermarket in which customers arrive with an intensity of 10 per hour.

The supermarket has 3 aisles, A,B and C. The probability of a customer going going to each aisle is 0.6,0.3,0.1

Then we want to find out the expected waiting time for 2 customers to go to aisle A, how would I go about this?

Am I just doing P(X=2) = 1-P(X<=1) firstly or ?

Haven't done questions like this before !

Comment: If you're doing this for practical purposes, to my intuition the probabilities would most likely normalize rather quickly. Because if 60% of the people choose aisle A, then the incoming people won't be choosing that one as often because there's a lot of people there, they will go to the other aisles instead. This will effectively increase the probability of the other two aisles getting customers, up to a certain point when all of them have normalized; and they're roughly getting a third of the customers each. This is assuming that the customers actually look and then choose their aisle.

Comment: @SamAnderson See I am trying to figure out how would I calculate it because it's a bit confusing for me in terms of how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

See I am trying to figure out how would I calculate it because it's a bit confusing for me in terms of how to go about it